# How do I use firebase storage from a client side React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage, create-react-app

I'm trying to write a file into cloud storage from within my React app. I created a new React app using the create-react-app tool. I believe I have followed the correct instructions to get a storage reference, with code like this: `this.storage = firebase.storage();`. But, no matter how I configure firebase and no matter what I import, I see this error: `TypeError: _this.firebase.storage() is not a function.`.

I tried importing `@firebase/storage` (commented out here) but this results in an error, and the NPM page for that module suggests this is not something a user should ever load directly.

I believe I added the proper firebase libraries. I can use firestore and the legacy database (I removed the code to do it, but it works if I use something like `this.firestore = this.firebase.firestore();`). But, storage is unresolved.

I'm a little unclear as to whether I should be using client libraries for cloud storage (I believe that is exactly the same thing as "storage" for Firebase). But, all the examples seem to be for accessing storage from a NodeJS app, and I want to write the file from within my browser context as client-side JavaScript.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "^0.3.2",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.5.2",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^0.5.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.3.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3009 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

My `index.js` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/auth';
//import '@firebase/storage';                                                                                                                  

var config = {
    apiKey: "ABCDEFG",
    authDomain: "abcdefg.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://abcdefg.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "abcdefg",
    storageBucket: "abcdefg.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "12345"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

class Index extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.firebase = firebase;
        this.firestore = this.firebase.firestore(); // This works fine.
        this.storage = this.firebase.storage(); // This fails
        console.log( "Got storage ref" );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <Index/>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

The firebase config is copied from the Firebase console (but changed here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works: `$ npm i @firebase/storage --save`.

This currently results in `"@firebase/storage": "^0.2.3"` inside `package.json`.

If I have that, I can use code like this in my `firebaseConfig.js` file to setup storage inside firebase:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/storage';
```

Then code like this works:

```
const storage = firebase.storage();
const files = [ 'image1.png', 'image2.png' ]; 
files.map( filename => {
    storage
      .ref( `/covers/${filename}` )
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then( url => {
        console.log( "Got download url: ", url );
      });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not importing firebase-storage, so that means the service won't be available in your code.

```
"@firebase/storage": "^5.1.0",
```

The rest of your code looks fine, once you add this dependency.

Comment: When I try `npm i --save @firebase/firebase-storage` I get `404 Not Found: @firebase/firebase-storage@latest`. This link is a 404 as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firebase-storage.

Comment: This does resolve https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/storage but says: "This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported firebase package."

Comment: Oops, I was wrong, even adding that manually to package.json does not work (`404 Not Found: @firebase/firebase-storage@^5.1.0`)

Comment: It should not. I'm actually not sure what's going on.

Comment: Hi Frank, now that we are past the weekend, do you know if there is a workaround, or a rollback option for me to get this working?

Comment: I'm not aware of this being a bug. I just don't see why you get that `404` when you're using the correct package. Maybe somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: If the package is `@firebase/firebase-storage` and the NPM site reports that package as missing, isn't that definitive that it is not the correct package name? If it were just me seeing when I run `npm i --save ...` then I could understand that there might be a networking issue or something, but on the NPM site it means either the package name is wrong or otherwise, right?

Comment: I think the issue was that you need to add `@firebase/storage` to the package.json, and then load it properly.

Comment: Aha... a mismatched package name. Good catch @xrd!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `firebase` to your app

```
npm i firebase
```

or

```
yarn add firebase
```

Please check in your `package.json` if the version of your firebase is `>9.0` because I will talk about that only.

By this time I also expect you to already have registered your app in Firebase console and have got your credentials. If not so then do that first.

In `/src/` folder of your project add a new file `firebase.js`

```
// src/firebase.js

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from "./constants/firebase";
import "firebase/compat/storage";

firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
export const storage = firebase.storage();
export default firebase;
```

In place of the `FIREBASE_CONFIG` place your credentials object.

Next make a new file to create a function

```
// src/services/firebase/firebase.service.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { storage } from "../../firebase";

export class FirebaseService {
  uploadToFirebaseStorage(files = []) {
    let urls = [];
    if (files.length > 0) {
      files.map((file) => {
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/img/${file.name}`).put(file);
        uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          (snapshot) => {
            const progress = Math.round(
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            );
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
          () => {
            storage
              .ref("img")
              .child(file.name)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then((newUrl) => {
                urls.push(newUrl);
                console.log(newUrl);
              });
          }
        );
      });
      return urls;
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want the function only copy paste the function from here.

Now this `files` prop will accept an array of files / images and it will give back `urls` which is an array of links where you can access the uploaded files.

Here the `storage` is the same as which I exported from earlier.

A sample to call this function I have also showed here.

```
src/App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FirebaseService } from "./services/firebase/firebase.service";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const fbs = new FirebaseService();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        type={"file"}
        onChange={(e) => {
          let temp = files;
          temp.push(e.target.files[0]);
          setFiles(temp);
        }}
      ></input>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("Hi");
          fbs.uploadToFirebaseStorage(files);
        }}
      >
        Upload
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```